# Why is this sentence incorrect?

Tags: definite-articles, determiners

In my understanding, determiners are categorized into three subgroups: predeterminers, central determiners and postdeterminers. Articles (a, an, the) and possessive determiners are identified as central determiners.

<del>In my book</del>, Is the following sentence <del>is identified as</del> correct?
I believe it is.

> This is the Tim's book.

However, this sentence does not sound right even though the two sentences used same determiner from the same group.

> This is the my book.

Comment: sentence A has a problem. Unless there is more than 1 Tim and the article is modifying Tim to tell us which one, it is in error.

Comment: I don't recognize the terminology of the book you're quoting, but the grammarian in my head (who is frequently wrong, btw) thinks that *my*, *Tim's*, and *the* are all **mutually exclusive** options for the single particle that goes in the slot between "this is" and "book".  In other words, you can't write "This is the my book" for the same reason you can't write "This is the a book".

Comment: If that sentence is in the book, throw it away. If, on the other hand, you made it up, then you should know that articles cannot occur with other determiners modifying the same noun. So **the my book* and **the Tim's book* are both ungrammatical. _The book, a book, my book, Tim's book, that book_ are all correct; one determiner each.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based upon a terrible grammar textbook.

Comment: @DavidM hah! That should be made an official off-topic reason.

Comment: Could you please copy the phrases that come before "This is the Tim's book"? It might be you have misunderstood the explanations. For example the series [*New English File*](https://elt.oup.com/student/englishfile/?cc=it&selLanguage=it) as far as I know is written only in American English and British English.

Comment: I think that I made up a mistake for this question. The example sentenecs are made up by me. I just wondered if the(determiner) and my(possessive) can occur at the same time.

Comment: Another better example sentence might be this. ex) We found the boy's notebooks under the table. This sentence is from my test paper. It has the and boy's which are deteminer and possessive determiner, repectively.

Comment: In "the boy's notebooks" "the" is the determiner for "boy", not "notebook".

Comment: We've clearly all understood "in my book" as referring to a grammar textbook you have, but do you mean [this idiom instead](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+my+book)? If so I recommend editing it to say "in my understanding" instead.

Comment: I've just edited, which I didn't edit in the first place. Actually someone did it for me. Now I understand. So, I can say, I found the Judy's book which the(determiner) modifies Judy not book.

Comment: The first sentence would be correct if _Tim_ was being used as slang for [_Roman Catholic_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tim).

Comment: This question is obviously not general reference.  It's also wrong to close this as off-topic claiming that the book is incorrect.  The OP invented these sentences!  They never said the book claimed they were correct. This claim was introduced by [medica's edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/160726/revisions), which was unfortunately in error and appears to have led to the closure of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You textbook is grossly incorrect.  Neither of those sentences is correct unless you have strangely named items that require books.

To dissect this problem look at the sentence more carefully:

Would you say:

> This is the Tim.
>   This is the me.  (My is the possessive form of me)

If the answer is no, then you would likewise never use the possessive forms of those structures.

The only way you would say that is if you have an object called a Tim and there is only one of them.  Likewise an item called a me ...

The correct way to state this is:

> This is Tim's book.  (No article required.)
>   This is my book.  (No article required.)

Comment: The OP invented these examples. The reason you mistakenly believed the textbook said they were correct, and the reason you declared the textbook terrible, was medica's edit, which was in error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general rule that in the position of the article (the, a/an) you can only use one sort of "article-words".
You can say 1 my little dog or 2 the little dog, but can't use two article words in the article position.
So *the my dog is wrong.
The sense of this rule is clear. When you use an article word such as "the, this, my" you make a selection of what you speak.
Either you point to the thing you talk about (this thing) or you talk about a thing that belongs to you (my thing)  or you indicate 
that you talk about something that  was just talked about and the person talked to knows exactly of what thing you talk (the thing)
or you talk about a thing the other person does not know (a  thing).
With one sort of article words the thing talked about is clearly defined or selected.  So it is not reasonable to indicate two 
criteria of selection.

Answer (score 0):

Books, when not referred to by title, are in the category of *[count nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)* in English: intuitively, discrete items that can be readily *counted*.  (Contrast *[mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)*: rice, sand, water.)  The “standard” varieties of English<sup>1</sup> require *[determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)* in front of most uses of count nouns.  *The* and *a* are the most common determiners, but other words can play the role.  Only the starred sentences below are incorrect:<sup>2</sup>

> This is a book
>   This is the book
>   This is my book
>   This is Tim’s book
>   This is the farmer’s book

but

> *** This is book   *(determiner may not be completely omitted)*
>   *** This is the my book  *(“my book” is sufficient, an extra* the *is not allowed)*
>   *** This is farmer’s book *(“farmer” is itself a count noun, so it too must have a determiner)*

Now, compare “Tim’s book” and “farmer’s book.”  *Farmer* is a count noun.  *Tim* is also technically a count noun. There are many people named Tim, you can have a specific number of them in a room, etc.  But a more specific rule triggers: *Tim* is a *proper* noun.  Even though there are many people named Tim, they are not considered to be interchangeable the way “farmers” might be.  If you just say “Tim” you are, normally, speaking of a *specific person*, and your interlocutor will probably demand clarification if it’s not obvious which one.  (“This is Tim’s book” -> “Tim from the bowling alley?” -> “Yeah, him.”) Therefore, *Tim’s* all by itself works as a determiner:

> This is the farmer’s book
>   This is Tim’s book
>   *??* This is the Tim’s book

I’m not going to say the sentence tagged with two question marks is *wrong*, but it would require an unusual context where “Tim” was acting as a *role* rather than a proper name.  In a theatrical production, perhaps, “the Tim” could mean “the actor who is playing the role of Tim today.” But even then, a book that this character needs to carry onstage at one point would probably be referred to as “Tim’s book” and not “the Tim’s book.”

<sup>1</sup> I would not be at all surprised to learn that varieties of English with recent influence from other languages have different rules for determiners.

<sup>2</sup> Descriptivist’s “correct” and “incorrect” = “native speakers of this variety of this language consistently and unconsciously honor this rule, except for deliberate stylistic effect.”